# Verification of sign up

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I wrote a new form of signup. But it's done vice versa what I need. I show code exists if it's in DB and bypass sing-up if there is any. But I need that it shows: "Wrong code" if "sec_code" not found in my DB (created already a list of these codes) and bypass if it exists in DB. Thx. Stuck on this.

```php
    if($_GET['action'] == "save")
    {
            $sec_code    = htmlspecialchars($_POST['sec_code'], ENT_QUOTES, '');
            $yes    = intval($_POST['yes']);


            if(!$sec_code) {
                $error = "<p class=\"er\"></p>";
            } 

            elseif(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT skey FROM users WHERE sec_code = '".$sec_code."'"))) {
                $error = "<p class=\"er\">Security code exist!</p>";
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use that code? It's totally unsafe in this day and age.

Comment: I understand that it's bad secure but there is no confidential data will be in...

Comment: I want that it was simple If exist entry in base it sign up if don't exist in base get error. Not vice versa as now.

Comment: It's best that you consult the duplicate(s). Your (better) solutions are in there; trust me.

Comment: I am confused :) What do you mean? I think it probably easy to write some lines. But how to do it with if-else?